# How to embed Meteor into another page?

Tags: meteor

If you want to provide a "embed code" to another person so they can  embed a meteor widget into their own webpage / cms etc.  One options would be to do an iframe, but thats not too friendly to mashing up stuff.  So ideally I'd want it so I can render HTML into the DOM of the host page.

As an example imagine if you wrote a chat app in meteor and wanted to allow people to be able to embed it into their own page.  That page may also have various other things on it other than the chat, in fact the chat meteor server is completely different from the server providing the host page.

Is there a good way of doing this?

Comment: if you are not running in an iframe then you'll have cross-domain issues: even if you got the meteor app onto the page, it wouldn't be allowed to talk to the meteor server (unless it is the same as the server serving the page itself), so none of the real-time data exchange between client and server would be working.

Comment: @ChristianFritz supposedly cross origin websockets is possible.